# Realtime recording while listening for input

Tags: python, multithreading, bash, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm currently running a python 2.7 script, using two threads running concurrently. One thread consistently looking for input (raw_input at the moment) activating a global variable when it gets one. The other consistently records using bash ffmpeg commands with subprocess. When the global variable of the former thread is active the latter thread triggers an event.

My problem is that while the second thread is recording video from a stream, I can't input anything and the breaks between recordings are really short. So basically it keeps recording for 30 seconds and overwriting itself without allowing me to activate the variable to save the current file somewhere.

I've tried to run the ffmpeg in subprocess in the background by using the & and by hiding it's output but did not have much success there.

Can anyone help me with this, preferably with a small example?

My basic recording thread currently:

```
from subprocess import Popen
Last30S_Command = (["ffmpeg", "-i", "rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.25.179:554/Streaming/Channels/1", "-r", "30", "-vcodec", "copy", "-an", "-t", "30", "-y", "/Path/Last30S.mp4"])

subprocess.call(Last30S_Command)
```

Comment: Because threads cannot run concurrently in Python, you should consider multiprocessing instead.